# Motorcycle stood for over 12 months, turn over by hand first?

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, gsxr

My 2006 GSXR 750 has been stood for over 12 months, I have drained the tank, and oil, and I'll do the coolant after I get it started, and give it another oil change.

Is it worth me removing the plugs and turning it over by hand a few times, before I attempt to start it?

Also, is it worth me replacing the fuel filter?

p.s. the bike has been dry stored.

Comment: By "dry stored" do you mean there hasn't been *any* fluids (oil, gas, etc) in the bike? Or do you mean it's been in a garage?

Comment: @Paulster2 - Dry stored as in it's been in a garage.

Comment: Has it got a timing belt or chain? if its a belt it may be worth replacing (depending on the age) My bike has two belts (v-twin) that require replacing at least every 2 years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have stored a vehicle for an extended period of time and did not prepare it for storage properly by draining the fuel it seems you should consider doing the following things.

1. Drain all gas from the entire fuel system
2. Replace fuel filter in the gas tank and if you have one in your fuel line you should change that too
3. Try and charge your battery, if it's bad, replace it.
4. Clean batter connection points
5. Check your tires for dry rot.  Probably ok but it's a motorcycle so you should check.
6. Test all lights.  Blinkers, tail and brake.  I'm not saying storing the bike would have issues but as my dad said, "always test your safety equipment honey, unless you want to die."
7. Disassemble your carbs and use carb cleaner to clean out the jets and all the passageways inside the carbs.  You can also get a carb parts dip and soak the carbs in it for a few hours.  The old gas can evaporate leaving a thick nasty gunk behind inside of the carbs.
8. Remove your fuel pump from the gas tank.  There is a fuel filter in it.  You take the pump out of the housing and clean the screen.
9. Check your intake manifolds, rubber, make sure there are no cracks.
10. Change oil and filter
11. Clean/replace your air filter.
12. Clean the pvc valve foam thing in your airbox.  I guess it's a filter for particles but doesn't make sense to me.
13. Spark plugs - I would change them but they are probably fine.
14. Yes, put a little oil in your cylinders, it will make sure your rings on the piston are operating nicely against the bore of your cylinder on the first few spins of the engine once it's started.  You can put in gear on a stand and turn it over with the rear wheel by pulling it up.  If I can do it, you can do it.  If it doesn't want to turn.  You might have a problem like rust in the cylinder.  That would be bad.
15. Yes, change your coolant.
16. Check your chain.  Tighten it and lube it with chain lube, not engine oil.  :)   Chain lube is sticky and won't get flung off your chain.
17. Test your brakes but I would suck out all the old brake fluid just because that's how I would do it.  I really don't know if that's the right thing to do but as dad said, "check all your safety equipment unless you want to die."
18. Check your ignition switch.  When the bike is running, wiggle the key in there a bunch.  I had a bike that I pulled out of storage and when driving down the road it cut out.  I almost crashed.  There was arcing in it.  I don't know if it was because of moisture from storage but now I ALWAYS wiggle my key around a bit when doing maintenance to make sure I don't lose power once I'm riding.

Comment: That's a good list

Comment: A 2006 GSXR 750 is fuel injected - no carbs

Answer (score 7):

I would say **yes** to both of your questions. If you have some ATF (Dexron or whatever) sitting around, squirt a "bit" into each cylinder through the spark plug hole before you do this. You don't want to drop a whole bunch in there, but enough to wet the rings (a couple of squirts from an oil can or the like should be sufficient). This will create a small amount of white smoke when you first start the engine, but nothing to worry about as it will clear fairly quickly. Let the ATF sit in the cylinder for several minutes, then rotate the crank through several cycles (8-10 revolutions). You should be golden from there.

As for the fuel filter, the reason I say change it is because it won't hurt anything to do so.

Comment: All good points and I would add change the crank oil and filter. Any sediment or water in the oil should have settled and will come out with the oil. If you feel a lot of resistance to the crank turning let it sit overnight to allow the oil to free up the rings.